How to download editable PDF using pdf.js
I use the pdf.js library to display the pdf files that come from the server, and the problem I have is that when we click on the print button and want to save the file as a pdf, after saving the pdf, an image is saved. And the pdf is not a text and you cannot select the text
Do you have a solution for this?
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

I have added the URL of my pdf.js preview sample
To see the item, please click on the print button first and then click save as pdf. You can see that the file is saved as a pdf as an image and does not have the ability to edit and select the text. @KJ

How can I render text as pdf?@KJ

I understand your explanation, do we have a setting or configuration in the browser itself so that we can download pdf as text?
I searched and found nothing
It seems that the browser itself or pdf.js changes the file to an image pdf when downloading @KJ
